# Join two tables without proper link ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe8a6/25)** (`astAssets` is omitted to reduce complexity)

I need get a list of certain maintenance tasks for an asset, together with their respective subtasks and spares quantities.

The tasks are linked to the assets, and the subtasks and spares are both in separate tables linked to the tasks with ID's.

Thus, the following two queries will respectively get all subtasks and tasks from all assets

```
Select T.Code, ST.Description From astTasks T
    Join astTaskSubTasks ST ON ST.ParentId = T.Id
    Join astAssets A ON A.Id = T.AssetId

Select T.Code, S.StockItemId From astTasks T
    Join astTaskSpares S ON S.ParentId = T.Id
    Join astAssets A ON A.Id = T.AssetId
```

The description of the subtask records hold a stock item code. The spare records are linked to a stock item code with a `StockItemId`.

I want to get a list of all tasks in an asset, together with all subtasks and spares for those tasks. The subtasks and spares oftentimes (but not always) refer to the same stock items. E.g., task `A` holds a subtask which shows stock item `0990` will be replaced every 12 months, and therefore stock item `0990` has been listed in the spares list for this task.

Problem is that the subtasks and spares have no link between them, even though they sometimes are clearly related (as in the example above).

To make matters more complicated:

- Safety stock tasks hold spares but no subtasks (nothing has to be 'done')
- Some subtasks only require a stock item to be visually checked and therefore no corresponding spare is present
- Spares may be missing as a user mistake
- Both subtasks and spares are absent in a task which is another user error

**I want to list the stock item code, task, subtask description, and spares quantity even if subtasks, spares, or both are absent.** The query below does not work, as it can't link the spares to the subtasks. As a result, one stock item may be listed multiple times for the same task with different quantities, because it's getting the quantities from all spares in that task. As a result, you may wrongfully get 4 records for one stock item.

```
Select Distinct
 CASE WHEN ST.Description IS NULL THEN SI.Code ELSE LTRIM(SUBSTRING(ST.Description, CHARINDEX('x ' , Substring(ST.Description, PATINDEX('%(%[^A-Z]% x %', ST.Description),50) ) +  PATINDEX('%(%[^A-Z]% x %', ST.Description)+1, (CHARINDEX(') - (', ST.Description) - (CHARINDEX('x ' , Substring(ST.Description, PATINDEX('%(%[^A-Z]% x %', ST.Description),50) ) +  PATINDEX('%(%[^A-Z]% x %', ST.Description)))-1)) END
, T.Code
, Left(ST.Description, CHARINDEX(' ',ST.Description, 1))
, CASE WHEN Left(ST.Description, CHARINDEX(' ',ST.Description, 1)) = 'Check' Then 'Check' ELSE CAST(S.Quantity as nvarchar) END
From astTasks T

Join astAssets A ON A.Id = T.AssetId 

Left Join astTaskSubTasks ST ON ST.ParentId = T.Id
Left Join astTaskSpares S ON S.ParentId = T.Id
Left Join stkStockItems SI ON SI.Id = S.StockItemId

Where
A.Code = '2016404991'
```

The image below is a screen grab from the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fe8a6/25) and shows the issue. Top table is a list of all spares (col 2) in their respective tasks (col 1) with the corresponding quantities (col 3). The second table was constructed with the query above. As you can tell, it displays stock item codes with the wrong spare quantities. It just shows all possible combinations for that particular task & stockitem.

[image: Problem]

Comment: I don't see astAssets in your SQL fiddle.

Comment: I have omitted it to reduce complexity. astAssets would specify the tasks I select but because of the small number of tasks I have included this is not necessary

Comment: "even though they sometimes are clearly related (as in the example above)."   I fail to see how the example shows a clear relationship.   You need to make it possible to understand your question without referencing the fiddle, because one day that fiddle will become a dead link to nothing.

Comment: "task A holds a `subtask` which shows stock item `0990` will be replaced every 12 months, and therefore stock item `0990` has been listed in the `spares` list for this task". The task would be a SERV-12M, with a subtask with description `Replace 0990`, and a corresponding spare record for 0990 with a quantity.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Thanks for the fiddle & link. But please also put everything necessary to you question in the post itself. [ask] Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "Links" & constraints are not needed to query. They make some expressions return the same result as others when they wouldn't otherwise. A table represents a relation(ship)/association, and a query returns rows satisfying one given that base tables satisfy theirs. When a row is in a base table what does it state about the situation? When a row is in the desired result, what does it state about the situation and/or what rows are in the base tables?

Comment: @philipxy Although I agree I ought to have included a desired output, I tried to explain the matter to the best of my ability. I hope this answers your question: if one of 6 spares is stock item '0990', my query would return not one but 6 records for this single stock item with all the different quantities in this spares list (obviously only one of these is correct).

Comment: I have added a screenshot to illustrate the problem

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot, which has some content not as easily expressed by just text. But please also give all that can be text as text. My standard comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for adding explanation. For the future: Best query specification is per my comment--"Row (code, ...) is in the result when row (T.AssetId, ...) is in astTasks & row (A.Id,...) is inastAssets & ... & A.Id=T.AssetId & ... or ((there's no T.AssetId where A.Id=T.AssetId) & T.assetId is null & ...) ... [etc etc]". More standard comments: 'This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution.' & 'Please clarify via edits not comments.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should have provided some "expected output" for the sample data given in the sqlfiddle. I'd lie if I said it was easy to understand what you need, and I'm still not sure I've got it right.

So basically the way this works is that it tries to extract the part id from the task description (subTasks CTE), and then tries to match the spare record from there (SubTasksWithMatchingSpares CTE). All the remaining spares for a given task, that cannot be matched against a subtask, are listed separately (WithoutSubtasks CTE). Then both result sets are unioned together to provide the full list of task -> subtask -> spare + task -> spare.

```
;WITH subTasks AS
(

    SELECT ST.Id
         , ST.ParentId
         , Description
         , SI.Id AS StockItemId         
      FROM astTaskSubTasks ST
     -- Find the space, delimiting the verb from part code, if any
     CROSS
     APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', ST.Description) spaceIndex) x1
     -- Extract the part code
     CROSS
     APPLY (SELECT RIGHT(ST.Description, LEN(ST.Description) - x1.spaceIndex) AS PartCode) x2
      -- Related stock item
      LEFT OUTER
      JOIN stkStockItems SI
        ON SI.Code = x2.PartCode
),
-- Match spares against the spare codes extracted from subtask description, if there is one
SubTasksWithMatchingSpares AS
(
SELECT T.Id AS TaskId
     , T.Code AS TaskCode
     , ST.Id AS SubTaskId
     , ST.Description AS SubTaskDescription
     , ST.Id
     , ST.StockItemId AS SpareId
     , TS.Quantity AS SpareQuantity
  FROM astTasks T
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN subTasks ST 
    ON ST.ParentId = T.Id
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN astTaskSpares TS
    ON TS.ParentId = T.Id
   AND TS.StockItemId = ST.StockItemId
),
-- Leftover task spares that were not matched against the subtask description
WithoutSubtasks AS
(
SELECT T.Id AS TaskId
     , T.Code AS TaskCode
     , SI.Code AS Code
     , TS.Quantity AS SpareQuantity
  FROM astTasks T 
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN astTaskSpares TS
    ON TS.ParentId = T.Id
 INNER
  JOIN stkStockItems SI
    ON SI.Id = TS.StockItemId 
   -- check if the subtask successfully matched it
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subTasks checkIfAlreadyMatched
                     WHERE checkIfAlreadyMatched.ParentId = TS.ParentId
                       AND checkIfAlreadyMatched.StockItemId = TS.StockItemId)

),
AllTogether AS
(
-- All tasks will be here, whether subtask matched or not; if it did, it also matched against the spare
SELECT ST.TaskId
     , ST.TaskCode
     , ST.SubTaskId
     , ST.SubTaskDescription
     , SI.Code
     , ST.SpareQuantity
  FROM SubTasksWithMatchingSpares ST
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN stkStockItems SI
    ON SI.Id = ST.SpareId
 -- check to match tasks without a subtask that have been matched against a spare
 -- to avoid empty records, if such a match exists
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM WithoutSubtasks withoutST 
                    WHERE withoutST.TaskId = ST.TaskId
                      AND SI.Code IS NULL)


UNION ALL
-- Only tasks that have a spare are here, and the spare was not matched against a subtask
SELECT ST.TaskId
     , ST.TaskCode
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , ST.Code
     , ST.SpareQuantity
  FROM WithoutSubtasks ST
 )
 SELECT * FROM AllTogether
 ORDER BY TaskId
```

[sqlfiddle results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/29eafe/4)

Comment: I just tried the fiddle, and it seems to work as intended. I will try to apply this to my DB and report from there

Comment: Looks really impressive. However, the query always shows an empty record (that is, no stockitem code nor a quantity) for SAFS tasks, regardless whether spares are linked to these tasks. Such an empty record would indicate the absence of SubTasks and Spares, but this is not always the case. I have updated  [your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/74808/1) which shows what I mean!

Comment: @TimStack Ok, I see. I edited my answer with an updated query, checking if a task had been matched against a spare so that an empty record is not returned when such match occurs. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/29eafe/4)

Comment: Excellent! Your query does exactly what I had in mind, I am just not proficient enough yet to put it into a working query myself. Your time and effort is greatly appreciated

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help. If you need any part explained, just ask away.

Comment: I can tell _how_ you are linking and comparing tasks, spares, and subtasks, but I am not familiar enough with CTE's. From a quick glance it would appear that, with the final `SELECT` statement, you are extracting the data from the larger `WITH` statement, but the workings of the latter are yet unclear to me. I would assume you are creating some sort of temporary table, if not plural..

Comment: CTEs, common table expressions, are kind of like subqueries, in that `;WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = 1) SELECT * FROM cte` is pretty much the same thing as `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = 1) subquery`. The biggest upside to CTEs is that they are treated as tables, so you can refer to a CTE in any other CTE that follows after it. We could dump data from a CTE into a `#temporaryTable` and use that as well, and it's a common optimization technique to do so, but I didn't feel it's necessary here.

Comment: _"The biggest upside to CTEs is that they are treated as tables, so you can refer to a CTE in any other CTE that follows after it"_. That's what I got from looking through your query. Really useful. Cheers for the help